# CTRL A gives me erroneous value in VIM with huge number

Tags: vim

Suppose I write a number `23456`, I try to add 2 to it,so i press 2 then `Ctrl A` by keeping the cursor on the first number, i get correct result as `23458`.

But, when it comes to a huge number  like `"33333333333333333333333333399999999999999999999999932"` and then i try to add 2 , by pressing 2 and then `CTRL A` , i get a garbage(i don't know what to call it) value as `"1733895256476221375"`. I don't know what is happening.Am i missing here something?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance, I am using GVIM on linux 7.3 version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim internally uses integer arithmetic; it has no notion of arbitrarily large numbers. Therefore, the result is limited to signed 32-bit (so far also in 64-bit versions of Vim (at least on Windows)); i.e. the maximum value is 0x7fffffff = 2147483647.

You can probably perform the low-digit addition in your head, and then use `r{number}` to adapt the number.

Comment: Okay,Thanks for the info,at least i know the issue now.